# Python / Pythonista GUI Multi-Menu

Tags: python

I am new to python and I am trying to create a multi-menu that can execute another program I have. I have the menu down but I can't get the action result to open the other program. Here is what I have so far:

```
import ui
import console

@ui.in_background
def button_tapped(sender):
    alert_result = console.alert('SSpy Menu',     'Select Version', 'v1.0.3', 'v1.4.7')
    choice = alert_result()
    exec_menu(choice)

button = ui.Button(title='Run')
button.action = button_tapped
button.present('sheet')

# Run SSPY v1.0.0
def v1():
    main()

# Run SSPY v1.4.7
def v14():
    sspy14()

# Run SSPY v2.0.5
def v2():
    sspy2()

# Show Versions
def ver():
    versions()

# =======================
#    MENUS DEFINITIONS
# =======================

# Menu definition
menu_actions = {
    'v1.0.3': v1,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

!!! Never Mind I Solved It !!!
I was thinking and realized I could make it an if statement which worked...

```
if sender.title == ('Button 2'):
        main()
```

Comment: Take a look at the dialogs module.  that is what it is for